# brackets install fails

Tags: software-installation

Trying to install brackets code editor from the Github Repo. They say it's available for Linux.

I downloaded a .deb, and run:

`sudo apt install <package>.deb`

But I get libcurl3 is not installable.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You haven't provided your OS & release details, but `apt` will assume you provide a path (you didn't in your example); a relative path "./" is likely easiest but `apt` has improved in later releases and you've not provided any specifics.

Comment: Using `rmadison` I can see that `libcurl3` has not been available in the Ubuntu repos since `libcurl3 | 7.58.0-2ubuntu2    | bionic/universe  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` which was 18.04.  I would file a bug or a request with Brackets to get the file changed to libcurl4 in their code.

Comment: Or wait to see if they update their app to work with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Terrance alright. Thanks